# React without jsx, can I use template strings instead of createElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I like the virtual dom diff concept of react where it redraws all the components. I'd like to not use webpack and jsx though. I was looking at this article:

http://jamesknelson.com/learn-raw-react-no-jsx-flux-es6-webpack/

but it seems the author is using React.createElement to create each one of the elements and I would rather use a template string:

```
function render() {
var whatever = 1;
var str = `<div> 
           ${whatever}
           </div>`;
return str;
}
```

Is this possible? can I just create everything as templated strings and still use the render() concept of react?

The thing I like about react is that it how it efficiently redraws the entire app based on the virtual dom diffing, that's why I want to keep the render() aspect of it. it reminds me of the way people write video games where at each frame the whole scene is redrawn.

Comment: That's only possible because JSX / `createElement()` gives it a tree instead of a string.  You probably want https://github.com/WebReflection/hyperHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can create elements and stroe them in a var similar to this, but they will be inside of {} instead of ' '